# Import C++ lib into C# (Windows Phone)

Tags: c++, windows-phone

I have a header file in C++, with something like this:

```
namespace n1
{
    namespace n2
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I have a c# file, and I want to use this header file...
I was trying doing this:

```
using n1.n2;
```

But it didn't work...

This:

```
using n1
```

is recognized, but the second namespace doesn't..

Does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just reference a C++ header from a C# project. You can't use C++ lib from C#.

You need to manually wrap your lib into a C++/CX wrapper that can be called from the C# managed code. Compile that wrapper. Then reference the compiled DLL + WinMD files (or the complete C++/CX project that builds that DLL so the visual studio will reference the DLL ).

Only then you'll be able to use your lib from C#.

**Update 2016:** Microsoft has fixed their [DllImport] long ago, in Windows Phone 8.1.
It is often a good idea to use [DllImport], and wrap the library into a normal C++ DLL with C-style API, without any C++/CX involved.

In the managed project, don’t forget to redistribute the native DLL, and also add dependency to the correct version of Visual C++ runtime library.